# Printing String Attribute Inherited from SuperClass shows Null

Tags: java, inheritance

I am extending a class and using  the super keyword to in my subclass constructors.

However, when I attempt to print the inherited attribute String. It returns null

```
public class Question implements IQuestion, Serializable {

private String question;

public Question(String question){
    this.question=question;
}

@Override
public String getQuestion(){
return question;
```

}

```
public class TrueFalseQuestion extends Question implements ITrueFalseQuestion{

String question;
boolean answer;

public TrueFalseQuestion(String question, boolean answer){
    super(question);
    this.answer=answer;  
}

@Override
public String getQuestion(){
return question+" True/False?";
}
@Override
public boolean checkAnswer(boolean answer){
    return this.answer==answer;
    
}
}
```

So when I create a TrueFalseQuestion object and call its getQuestion() method,

I get output: null True/False?

Why is it not printing the question I passed when creating the object? How can I correct this?

Thank you

Comment: 1. Remove the `question` field from the `TrueFalseQuestion` class. 2. Change `question+" True/False?"` to `getQuestion()+" True/False?"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's coz of the scope of the access modifier on the parent and child classes.

In class `Question` set the scope of the `question` variable to something less restrictive. eg

```
protected String question;
```

and in the child class, `TrueFalseQuestion`, remove the variable definition altogether so that the child will reference the parent variable.

```
String question; // <--- remove this
```